# Program is not playing music Nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

im new to nasm (I have used Tasm) and my program isn't playing the music at all
here is my code:

```
bits 16
org 100h
DATASEG 
sound_pointer dw 0
sound_data:
    incbin "abba.wav"   ;1,556,480
CODESEG
start:
    mov cx, 556480
    mov ax, 0
    mov [sound_pointer], ax
looper:
    mov dx, 22ch
    mov al, 10h
    out dx, al
    mov si, [sound_pointer]
    mov al, [sound_data+si]
    out dx, al
    mov ax, 1
    mov [sound_pointer], ax
    loop looper
```

r

Comment: There's more to soundblaster PCM playback than just writing samples to the DSP. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306701/how-to-write-a-simple-soundblaster-16-driver-using-direct-write-mode-for-a-hobby  Also, you seem to have pretty much no delay in between sample writes. And a WAV file (if that's what it really is) [contains more](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) than just the sample data.

Comment: Also, I don't know if nasm's `incbin` directive has some sort of support for handling that, but if that audio file really is 1,556,480 bytes then it won't fit in a segment.

Comment: thank you for the attention, do you have any advice how make it work?